# Xcode ignoring architecture-specific EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, conditional-compilation

I have this in my Xcode .pbxproj file for iOS:

```
buildSettings = {
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = bin/arm/Debug;
    "EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES[sdk=iphoneos*][arch=arm64]" = (
        AES_AESNI.cpp
    };
    "EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES[sdk=iphoneos*][arch=x86_64]" = (
        AES_ARMV8.cpp
    };
```

However, Xcode is ignoring these directives entirely, trying to compile AES_AESNI.cpp in ARM64 builds and AES_ARMV8.cpp in x86-64 builds (a.k.a. Simulator).

These directives are working fine in the Mac OS version of the project to separate x86-64 and i386, with "iphoneos*" replaced with "macosx*" of course.  Deleting the "[sdk=iphoneos*]" portion has no effect: the problem seems to be with the architecture matching.

Xcode versions 7.3.1 and 9.2.0 both exhibit this problem.